# android - adb devices offline - CM 10.2

Tags: android, adb, cyanogenmod

I install CM 10.2 on my galaxy nexus (Android 4.2.2) . And it got stuck in boot loop.

Also I can connect to my device via adb tool.
but the problem is my device is offline :

```
0149C22514015008    offline
```

The Version of adb is 1.0.31

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your device to pc in debugging mode your android device will ask you allow your pc for debugging. Make sure you allowed your pc. Try again by unplugging and plugging in usb.

Comment: As I said, I got stuck in CM boot loader , and don't have access to the device

Comment: Ohh sorry for that. Do you have custom recovery installed?

Comment: yes , I have twrp, can I push any data into my device in twrp?

Comment: yeas. by mounting your usb storage